# Arredondamento de valor para cima php não funciona

Tags: php

Quero transformar o valor retornado de uma soma, formatado sem caracteres ponto(.) ou vírgula(,)

`$valor` vem de um *POST*, em seguinte é feito uma soma:

```
echo $porcent * ceil($valor);
```

O código acima me retorna o seguinte valor *99.99* ou maior 999.99 acredito, daí quero que esse valor retorne *9999* sem ponto ou vírgula. Estou batucando o coco e não obtenho resultado.

---

Segue o código.

```html
<?php $valor = $_POST['valor']; $porcent = $_POST['porcent'] / 100; ?>
</head>
<body>
    <span style="width:40px" class="text-muted"><?php echo $porcent * ceil($valor); ?></span>
```

Comment: Dê exemplo numérico, quem é $porcent e quem é $valor

Comment: Se você está multiplicando um inteiro dado pela função ceil por um valor não inteiro é evidente que isso pode resultar em um numero não inteiro. faça `echo ceil($porcent * $valor);`

Comment: Que valores você está passando pelo POST para `valor` e `porcent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você deve fazer o cálculo e depois arredonda o valor:

```
<?php
   $valor = 1863;
   $porcent = 20 / 100;
   $resultado = $porcent * $valor;
?>
<span style="width:40px" class="text-muted"><?php echo ceil($resultado);?></span>
```

[**exemplo funcional no ideone**](https://ideone.com/rcknEY)

Comment: Funcionou conforme esperava, porém me retornou seguinte noticia aviso:

Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in

pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você consegue neste alg ao invés deste valor arredondar para cima, ele apenas remover a formatação tipo: 34.87 para 3487

Comment: você comentou desse erro, mas fiz os testes aqui e não ocorreu nada e também no link que o amigo acima postou está funcionando corretamente

Comment: você pode usar essa função: number_format($resultado, 2, '', ''), onde vai a variável ou valor, depois o número de casas depois da vírgula, depois o tipo de separação de decimal e o tipo de separação de milhar (como você pode ver são aspas simples, sem nada, para que tudo fique junto, se você quiser separar por algumas coisa, é só colocar algo entre as aspas).

Comment: Já encontrei o erro, estava emitindo o valor no campo input com vírgula(,) e assim emitia o resultado porém me avisando isso... Você sabe se tem como eu fazer para que mesmo digitando o valor com vírgula ele faça a soma?

Comment: mas, qual soma?